# 28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, authentication, connection, odbc

Currently I have my code which persists some data to some SQL DB which are running in a docker container in a VM. However, now I need to persist the data to some SQL DB from Azure. On Azure I have a server and under it 7 databases, 6 are used by my code and the 7th is used by Airflow. After deploying it, I've noticed that I am successfully connecting to the airflow one ( there were no tables created, nor data and after deployment these got created), but for the others I get (must say that the user/server/pw are the same for all of them:

```
('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'X'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I logged in into the VM and inspected the container and checked the env, if the pw/server/user are passed correctly from the pipeline library and they are. In my pw I have some special characters(;$) and I tried to pass the password between curly braces in my connection string but still did not work. But still this makes no sense since I could connect to the airflow one. I just ran out of ideas. I also removed all images/volumes/containers before deployment.

This is the connection string used by Airflow:

```
AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mssql+pyodbc://${AIRFLOW_DB_USER}:${AIRFLOW_DB_PASSWORD}@${AIRFLOW_DB_SERVER}/${AIRFLOW_DB_NAME}?driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server&TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

This is the connection string used by the rest of the code:

```
connect_str = 'Driver={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};Server={server};Database={database};ENCRYPT=yes;UID={username};PWD={password};TrustServerCertificate=yes'             
engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={connect_str}")
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database though SSMS or Azure Data Studio using the credentials you're trying to pass for airflow?

Comment: @Xedni yes, all good

Comment: Silly as it may sound, it might be the `$` sign in the password. I had a problem with my airflow password containing a dollar sign, and I had to ask my admin to mint a new password without it. Once that was changed, the problem went away. Not sure a full list of special characters that throw it off, but i know alphanumeric and hyphens are fine.

Comment: yeah, I am thinking to change it too, however I was able to connect to airflow (one of the DBs) with the same pw tho via code. I will keep you posted

Comment: pw was the problem indeed

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: change password. My old password was having special characters like ( ; $, I just removed them and kept a plain password only with numbers and alphabetical characters in order to test if the pw is the problem or not. I was storing the password in the Pipeline Library and I was taking it from there.